# How to Read Data from s3 into Kafka (Docker image)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have installed  kafka on docker in windows, which is running as  below screenshot and I have installed "Amazon S3 Source Connector" by using this link
https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-s3-source/current/index.html#quick-start.

My Questions are :

i)How do I execute command to see all kakfa topics ( not through GUI)

ii)How do I check if S3 source connector is installed property (I mean location or cli..)

iii) And link also specifes to create and use "quickstart-s3source.properties" where do i do this? On my desktop on docker?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question title, that source connector does not read arbitrary S3 data, only that written by the S3 sink

> execute command to see all kakfa topics

`kafka-topics --list`

> check if S3 source connector is installed

You're only running the datagen connector, which doesn't include the S3 source, but you'd use the `/connector-plugins` endpoint of the Connect server

> specifes to create and use "quickstart-s3source.properties"

You need to convert this to JSON since Docker runs a distributed connect server, and those quickstart files are meant to be used with standalone. It doesn't matter where you create the file as long as it's given to the Connect server via HTTP POST